# Winter'21 Release - BEM Notation Change

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, bemnotation

Does BEM notation change have an impact on all of the components where SLDS is used?

Earlier the SLDS was being included as a static resource but off-late it is not necessary to do that.

In this link: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_slds_bem_deprecate.htm

the How part says : For your styles to continue working with SLDS 2.13.0 and later versions, replace -- with _ in your CSS. For example, replace slds-button--brand with slds-button_brand.

Should all the code where SLDS with this notation be changed?...since we don't explicitly mention the SLDS version in Aura Components, LWC any longer.

======================================================

Snapshot for Reference:

[image: Winter'21 Release - BEM Notation]

Comment: Just a note, that the release notes say it will be deprecated in Summer '21 even though it's mentioned in the Winter '21 notes. I would assume, unless you have a specific slds version in a static resource you're using, you will need to update all your references as it's pulling from the latest. Can't confirm that until Summer '21 is released in sandboxes next year.

Comment: To quickly identify old-style BEM syntax, you can use this regular expression to search .cmp, .html, and .page files: `class=".*--.*"` and `.*--.*` to find them in stylesheets.

Comment: Was is confirmed somewhere that custom CSS classes will also stop working on Summer'21? We've got a lot of those in our org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're still using the outdated Static Resource approach, you don't need to make any changes until/unless you move to the current version (recommended). If you do use the current version of SLDS (`force:slds`,`<apex:slds/>`,placing components directly in Lightning App Builder, etc), you need to fix the styles before the Summer '21 Release. Using VS Code with the Salesforce DX Bundle, you'll automatically get code fix prompts on files that need to be updated; they'll appear as blue underlines in your source code.

[image: Example Quick Fix prompt]

If you use standard components for styles, such as `lightning:input` or `lightning:layout`, you don't need to make any changes unless you are also using the class attribute on those components, *and* those styles are SLDS styles. Standard components have already been updated to use the latest styles.

If you don't directly use SLDS classes, you won't need to make any changes.

> Should all the code where SLDS with this notation be changed?

If you're still using the double-dash versions, you need to fix them. We've been given ample time to fix this, but time is running out. Now is the time to address those styles before they no longer work in about 6-9 months.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. I checked internally with our product management team. Any CSS that uses the old syntax should be replaced with the revised syntax.